# Ntile function in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have previously used ntile function in MS SQL in a project in R, but I need to change the database of the project in Mysql now. As per my knowledge Ntile is a window function in Sql Server,which is not present in Mysql. I have googled about this found the below link about ntile function documentation in Mysql.

[Mysql Ntile Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile)

I have tried the same way as described but still facing the error.

My query:

```
SELECT *, NTILE(10) OVER w AS 'ntile10' 
FROM test_table_name w AS (ORDER BY res_rate);
```

Any idea about the problem?
Is there any solution to overcome it?

Comment: Is MySQL on your server 8.0 version?

Comment: if you have not the mysql 8.0  the OVER clause is not available

Comment: ohhh..here goes the problem...
running query       SELECT VERSION(); I just got "5.7.19-log"...So i have to upgrade it then it can give result ..right??

Comment: Hi, I am using Mysql Community Version(Mysql Server 5.7 GA -- as per website). Is the upgrade to 8.0 can done here? or  I have to purchase the commercial version  for Mysql Server 8.0??

Comment: Hello @scaisEdge , @Whencesoever,  @Mike Lischke    I have installed the MySQL 8.0.1 -dmr-log ...but still after the running following code....`"select *,NTILE(4) over w as 'ntile4'
from test1 window w as(order by res_rate) "` giving the error

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `WINDOW` keyword:

```
SELECT *, NTILE(10) OVER w AS ntile1   
FROM test_table_name 
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY res_rate);
```

or:

```
SELCT *, NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY res_rate) AS ntile1
FROM test_table_name;
```